# Issue using functions (c++)

Tags: c++, function

so I am having a little bit of trouble getting this program to work without it throwing the errors:

"request for member 'insertArray' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'int [10]' " and

"request for member 'print' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'int [10]' ".

Both of those errors have to do with using my functions with an array, you can see the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int size = 0;
    int *arr;
    void insertArray(int val)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < size && arr[i] < val)
            i++;
        for (int k = size - 1; k >= i; k--)
        {
            arr[k + 1] = arr[k];
        }
        arr[i] = val;
        size++;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << "The array is: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[j];
        }
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int arr[10];
    
        cout << "Please enter 5 values: \n";
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int num = 0;
            cin >> num;
            arr.insertArray(num);   // Error 1: vs code error squiggles say: "expression must have class type"
            arr.print();  // Error 2: vs code error squiggles say: "expression must have class type"
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

I don't know how to fix the errors or what they mean either.

Thanks for the help in advance folks!

Comment: So many problems with passing around arrays in C++ are solved by *using `std::vector` instead*.

Comment: Yea I know::/ the only issue is I have to use an array

Comment: Oh, it's one of *those* courses. Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is just a plain-old C array, you can't define new functions on it. You need to define a `class` or `struct` if you want to do that.

What you have here is procedural code, so you're constrained by that model and must pass in `arr` as an argument.

I've tried to wrangle your original code into this form with as few modifications as necessary:

```
#include <iostream>

void printArr(const int* arr, const size_t size)
{
  std::cout << "The array is: ";

  for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    std::cout << arr[j];
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  const size_t count = 5;
  int arr[count];

  std::cout << "Please enter 5 values: \n";

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      std::cin >> arr[i];
  }

  printArr(arr, count);

  return 0;
}
```

The whole `insertArray` function was just too confusing so I deleted it presuming what you were trying to do was add things at the end of the array anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried that at first but didnt run it because I remember using vectors and functions like this : vector.function(). Completely forgot that I had to do that if its a standard array. Thanks again :)

Comment: Keep in mind *only* `struct` and `class` can have functions like that. Primitive types do not. `std::vector` is not a primitive type, so it can have all sorts of stuff contextual to it, while `int arr[X]` is just dumb data.

Comment: I've tried to fix your code here in an edit. It works on my machine™. Note the removal of `using namespace std;` as that's a bad habit to get into. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason.

Comment: Oh yeah the reason I had the insertArray is because I want the array to remain sorted as I input values. I did get it to work with your original answer though it was really great.

Comment: If you need to keep it sorted you can brute-force insert values, or you can use a binary insertion. You can also just call `std::sort` if permitted. You'll need to shuffle all values down one spot on insert, something your original code omitted.

Comment: I would have done that but we weren't allowed to use built in sort functions, and I figured adding the inset function was more efficient in terms of time complexity(in this very specific scenario).

Comment: I really hope you survive this course because it sounds singularly awful. Best of luck!

Comment: Its less so the course and really the professor and the situation with online courses. But yea, this course makes me feel like a complete idiot a lot of the time but I am sticking through it. I really appreciate the sentiment though :)